# Set theory confusion

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given a universal set  $\{ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 \} $,

$A$ is defined as ...

$A = \{ x : (x-1)(x-6) \lt 0 \}$

So what are the elements in $A$ , I'm a little confused here .

The $x$ values is $= 1$ or $6$.

So there's no elements in $A$ ?

Comment: Check the condition for each of these $9$ points, and the set $A$ contains only the ones for which the condition holds. If it makes it easier for you to understand, then: $A = \{ x \text{ such that } (x-1)(x-6) \lt 0 \}$.

Answer (score 1):

What $A$ is, is the set of all numbers $x$ in your universal set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ that fulfills the condition $(x-1)(x-6) < 0$. You would have $A = \{2,3,4,5\}$ since those are the numbers in your universal set for which $(x-1)(x-6) < 0$.

To see this you have for those that $x-6 < 0$, but $x-1>0$ which means that $(x-1)(x-6)<0$. On the other hand for $x=1$ and $x=6$ you would have $(x-1)(x-6)=0$ and if larger than $6$ you have $x-1>0$ and $x-6>0$ which means that $(x-1)(x-6)>0$ which means that no more than those numbers are in $A$.

Or if you weren't that smart you could just have inserted each of them into $(x-1)(x-6)$ and see which ones are negative.

Answer (score 0):

$(x-1)(x-6)<0$ when either of the following cases happens:

1) $(x-1)>0$ and $(x-6)<0$

2) $(x-1)<0$ and $(x-6)>0$

For case 1) $x>1$ and $x<6$. i. e. $x=2,3,4,5$

For case 2) $x<1$ and $x>6$ It is clear that there are no elements in the universal set for this case

So $A=\{2,3,4,5\}$

Comment: Why do we need to change the inequality sign ? For example why can't it be (X-1) < 0 , (X-6) < 0

Comment: I have not changed the inequality sign. If $(x-1)<0$ and $(x-6)<0$ their product is positive. But here the product should be negative.

Comment: @user307640 It's because if two factors are negative, their product will become positive. That is if $(x-1)<0$ and $(x-6)<0$ you will have that $(x-1)(x-6) > 0$.

Comment: I guess that you know that  1. product of two positive numbers is positive; 2.two negative numbers is positive and ; 3. product of a positive and a negative is negative.

Answer (score 0):

That is easy.. you have inequality. Take out critical points which are 1,6 .

Plot $1$ and $6$ on number line.

Now you have three regions on number line. 
Put a + sign on the extreme right hand side region. And then start putting alternating - and + from going right to left .

You will see - in the region from $(1,6)$ 
Which indicates that in this region.
$$(x-1)(x-6)<0$$

Hence Set can take the values between 1 and 6 excluding {1,6}

Therefore required set which satisfy he condition is ${2,3,4,5}$